# sudo add-apt-repository universe us not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, software-sources, add-apt-repository

I just upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 and ran `sudo add-apt-repository universe` on Ubuntu 22.04 and got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 363, in <module>
    addaptrepo = AddAptRepository()
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 41, in __init__
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/jammy
```